# Observador tipo bool C++

Tags: c++, poo, get, constructor, class

Estoy intentando resolver este ejercicio:

La clase Dados gestiona el lanzamiento de 2 dados.

- A) El constructor recibe dos parámetros opcionales con el valor inicial para el dado 1 y el dado 2 respectivamente. Si los dados no reciben valor inicial, éste se asignara a 1. Control de errores:
  si algún valor inicial no es correcto, el valor asignado será igual a 1.
- B) Observador get(). Tendrá 2 parámetros. El identificador del dado (1 o 2) y una referencia a un entero que almacenará el valor del dado correspondiente. Control de errores: si se produce algún error con el identificador del dado, get() debe devolver false, en caso contrario get() devuelve true.

Tengo dudas en el observador tipo bool, ya que no entiendo cómo puedo devolver true o false además del objeto.

Esta es la clase:

```
class Dados{

private:
  int dado1_, dado2_;

public:


  Dados(int valor1=1, int valor2=1){

    if (valor1>=1 && valor1<=6)
       {
        dado1_=valor1;
       }
    else dado1_=1;
    if (valor2>=1 && valor2<=6)
       {
        dado2_=valor2;
       }
    else dado2_=1;  
  }
```

He intentado hacer el observador así, pero no devuelvo dado1_ ni dado2_ :

```
bool get(int dado,int valor)
{
if (dado>=1 && dado<=2)
   {
    return true;
   }
else
   {
    return false;
   }
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Siempre podrías trucar un poco el asunto devolver una lista, y en las diferentes posiciones guardas el dado 1 el dado 2 i el true o el false. luego donde recojas la lista ya imprimes o usas lo que necesites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> b) Observador get(). Tendrá 2 parámetros. El identificador del dado (1
>   o 2) y una referencia a un entero que almacenará el valor del dado
>   correspondiente.

Esto significa que get() tendrá el siguiente prototipo:

```
bool get( int dado, int& valor);
```

`valorDado` en este caso actúa como parámetro de **salida**. Cuando una parámetro es una [referencia](http://c.conclase.net/curso/?cap=015) el valor que se asigne dentro de la función será usable cuando salgas de la función.

Considera el siguiente ejemplo :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool f1(int valor)
{
    valor = 5;
    return false;
}

bool f2(int& valor)
{
    valor = 7;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    int v;
    v = 3;
    f1(v);
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    f2(v);
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Al ejecutar ese código obtendrás este resultado :

> 3
>   7

En `f1` estamos pasando el parámetro por valor. Esto quiere decir que `f1` recibe una copia del parámetro pasado y que cambiar ese parámetro en `f1` no afecta a la variable con que se llamó a `f1`. Por eso el asignar `5` a `valor` no afecta a `v`.

Sin embargo `f2` recibe el parámetro por referencia, eso es lo que significa el `&`. En este caso `f2` recibe una referencia a la variable `v` y por eso cuando asignamos `7` a `valor` eso hace que `v` pase a valer `7`.

Imagino que en el futuro te enseñarán técnicas más avanzadas. Ten en cuenta que lo que estás haciendo es solo un ejercicio y no resulta representativo de lo que se hace en un programa real. Normálmente el valor del dado sería devuelto por get() y el control de errores se haría con excepciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Pero sigo sin entender cómo puedo devolver la referencia, lo estoy intentando así pero no funciona: bool Dados::get(int dado,int &valor)
{
  int *valor1;
  int *valor2;
if(dado!=1 and dado!=2){
  return false;
}
else{
  if(dado==1){
valor1=&valor;
    return true; }
  if(dado==2) {
valor2=&valor;
    return true; }
}
return true;
}

Comment: @Anita No tienes que devolver la referencia. Tienes que usarla para asignar el valor de salida.

Comment: Entendido! Muchas gracias :)